# How to apply transformation logic to values for a given key in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

Very new to Python and trying to learn the basics... coming from an ad hoc SQL background.

I do not understand how to iterate through a dictionary and apply transformations to values for a given key(column). For instance if column 2 header is 'Col2' and all the values are int's within it. How can I add 12 to each value within column 2.

`CSV` File contents: Just an example...

```
Col1 Col2 Col3  
Name 1 11  
Age 2 22  
Location 3 33  
State 4 44
```

Code:

```
import csv
import pprint


reader = csv.DictReader(open(r'file1.csv'))
result = {}
for row in reader:
    for k, v in row.items():
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

I'm lost after this.

Comment: can you show the content of your csv file?

Comment: please add it in question

Comment: Thanks, it's been added.

Comment: do you want to add `12` to each value in `Col2` and write the new value back to `csv` file?

Comment: In the end I would have a whole bunch of transformations across several columns. I would just want to store it back in the dictionary for now. Not sure if dictionary is best for this sort of thing. And I would assume it would be best if I stored each transformation for a column in a separate function?

Comment: shouldn't `Name`, `Age`, `Location`, be column instead of rows?

Comment: Sorry it's a bad example. Col1 would just be string column. Col1, col2, and col3 are the header names in my test file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert each column to `int` and then add a value you desire, read the comments below to get the idea of what is happening,

```
container = list() # use it later to modified modified row
with open("d:/a.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    next(csv_file) # this skip heading (first row)
    for row in csv_file:
        row = row.rstrip().split(",") #this gives you a row,
        row[1] = int(row[1]) + 12 #convert column1 of row in int and add 12
        container.append(row)

print(container)
```